# Taking it to the next level, systematically

Tags: resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Books that explain the science of cooking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9657/books-that-explain-the-science-of-cooking)

Hi there. 
I really like to cook, and I also like to experiment a bit with spices and ingredients, but I sometimes feel that the complexity of it all is overwhelming: How long and at what heat do I heat this? Which spice should be added at the beginning, which at the end? I feel that blindly experimenting will take ages to yield useful results.

What I don't like about most standard cook books is that they tell you step by step what you should do, but never explain why it is done. If they would tell, I could then start applying this knowledge in other places, I would understand which steps I could alter to achieve variations in taste and which steps are absolutely essential to avoid disaster.

Are there good resources that really teach and explain the art of cooking?