# What book/website should I read to help me move beyond just being able to follow a recipe?

Tags: cookbook, websites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Books that explain the science of cooking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9657/books-that-explain-the-science-of-cooking)

I am looking for a book/website or other resource to help me gain a deeper understanding of cooking and to help me move beyond just being able to successfully follow recipes. Although I can cook well I don't necessarily understand why things work, or why certain processes are necessary. Any suggestions?