# Good book on the chemistry of cooking?

Tags: chemistry, resources

What is a good book on the chemistry of cooking? I am looking for a book that discusses fermentation chemical reactions and reactions that occur when food is heated.

Comment: related (but not a duplicate, as it's more than just books) : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/9657/67

Comment: This seems to be opinion based.

Comment: GdD: yeah, it's a "list" question.  But it has an answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many books!  Here's a few:

- [Culinary Reactions](https://www.chicagoreviewpress.com/culinary-reactions-products-9781569767061.php) is probably the book that most directly addresses your question, since it's specifically cooking and chemistry.
- [The Food Lab](https://wwnorton.com/books/The-Food-Lab/) has quite a bit of chemistry in it.
- [Science and Cooking](https://bookshop.org/books/science-and-cooking-physics-meets-food-from-homemade-to-haute-cuisine/9780393634921) is both chemistry and physics.
- [Modernist Cuisine](https://modernistcuisine.com/), while about all the new cooking techniques, sure has a bunch of applied chemistry which is explained in the booth.

Comment: Your first recommendation is very good! It even discusses nixtamalization!

Answer (score 6):

The standard and most commonly referenced home-cook-approachable book on the science of cooking is *On Food and Cooking*, by Harold McGee.

Comment: This is the definitive book. Every other food science book I have references this one.

Comment: Darn, I knew I was forgetting one!

Answer (score 0):

I’m a fan of Shirley O. Corriher’s books for depth in what’s actually going on when cooking.  She was a biochemist, and was a semi-regular on Good Eats.  Her first two books explain some of the chemistry of what’s happening, the variables at play, and then presents a few recipes that show how you can change things up:

- [CookWise: The Hows & Whys of Successful Cooking, The Secrets of Cooking Revealed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0688102298)
- [BakeWise: The Hows and Whys of Successful Baking with Over 200 Magnificent Recipes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0017SYNV6)

She also has a new book that I haven’t read yet:

- [KitchenWise: Essential Food Science for Home Cooks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1982140682)

There’s also Cook’s Illustrated [The Science of Good Cooking](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00G4DIUR2), but it’s out of print, so you might instead one to look into the other ones that have already been mentioned (like The Food Lab)